# ValueError: signal only works in main thread in Flask using threading

Tags: python-3.x, flask, tkinter, python-multithreading

I use flask, tkinter and threading modules.
I need to run a tkinter process and a flask process to run at the same time and I want to use threading for that.
So I run

`t1 = t.Thread(target=lambda: root.wait_window(root))
t1.start()`

to start the tkinter part, and then

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=25000, debug=True)
```

to start the flask part. But it keeps returning "ValueError: signal only works in main thread" when I run the flask part. I tried putting the flask part into the thread and the tkinter part into the main program, but it returns the same error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you remove `if __name__ == '__main__':`?